# Should I get the Mortarboard Badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-badges

I'm a little confused. I just found the Mortarboard Badge which should be awarded for the first day with  200 reputation. When I look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I see the flowing text:

```
earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days
```

IMHO I should get that badget. But I saw that on that 200 rep day I got a 100 rep bonus. For the rep page that counts, for badges not?

Comment: Hmm - I don't think the reputation bonus counts as "earned" reputation. All other reputation (votes, accepts, bounties) does.

Comment: I would not ask if the reputation page would show zero days with 200 rep.

Comment: I don't know then. It can take a while for these things to be awarded though. How long ago was it?

Comment: @ChrisF Nov 18 '11

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I can't blame caching then :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The association bonus does not count for the mortarboard badge, by design.  It's not "earned reputation" on that day...not in the same way votes on your content is, I hope we agree there's a huge difference in the source there.

There may be tweaks to the badge in the future as it leaves out some other things that are much more trivial to include now...but I doubt the association bonus will ever be one of them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was just wondering because on the rep page was already one day counted.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that (at least some) [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1260/unstable?tab=reputation) [users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1322/colin-k?tab=reputation) who exceeded 200 rep *only* on a day including the Association Bonus do not have the Mortarboard badge.  I suspect this is intentional.

Comment: So is this an official statement?

Comment: @rekire I am not qualified to make an *official statement* -- it is simply an observation of the present situation.

Comment: I agree with you. I just saw that you are a moderator on a other SE Site, so I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @rekire for reference, I believe that those qualified to make *official statements* will have the ♦ [on all sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts).

Comment: From [List of all badges with full descriptions # Regular badges (M-Z)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258): *Reputation points earned for associating accounts or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do **not** count for the badge.*