# I passed 200 reputation but I haven't gotten the Mortarboard badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges

After I earned the 200 reputation points in a day, I should get the "Mortarboard" badge, but I didn't.

> [image: Image1]

> [image: Image2]

Does anybody knows, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The association bonus isn't considered for the MortarBoard badge. Details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Your reputation without the association bonus for yesterday is 138.

Comment: They should write that on the main badges page... (

Comment: @SeniorJD you can start new feature request asking for this. "Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day, excluding bonuses" sounds reasonable and still short enough to me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Are you kidding? I really can do that!

Comment: @SeniorJD yes you can suggest (it's matter of posting new question and tagging it with [meta-tag:feature-request] but no guarantee it will be done of course.

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185788/clearly-state-that-mortarboard-badge-requirements-excludes-bonuses)

Answer (score 4):

100 of your 238 reputation came from the association bonus. [This rep does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135269/189912) toward Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a while for the script to run that identifies these types of things. I'm sure after a little while, you will get your badge. Just be patient

Comment: But I'm already waiting for 14 hours!

Comment: Certain scripts don't run everyday. Some run only once a week