# Clearly state that Mortarboard badge requirements excludes bonuses

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-badges, badge-description

In [an earlier question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185730/i-passed-200-reputation-but-i-havent-gotten-the-mortarboard-badge) today, I was somewhat confused about the exact rules for earning the Mortarboard badge.

To prevent this, I think the Mortarboard badge's description should be changed to **Earning at least 200 reputation in a single day, excluding account association bonuses**.

Comment: Instead of saying "someone tell me to do this", why not give a real reason and elaborate more in the question?

Comment: Maybe `excluding account association bonuses` would be clearer. I initially wondered what bonuses you were talking about.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this will make it bit too long, in my opinion.

Comment: @Sha, it would still be shorter than `Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x` (Populist badge description ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) badge has a longer title anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally agree. Current state of Mortarboard badge is somewhat like:

[image]

I think this is something that we should think about.
There are several meta questions regarding the same ("*Why is Mortarboard badge not awarded?*") ..you can see some of them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135248/should-i-get-the-mortarboard-badge), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173381/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge) and [here too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178811/mortarboard-badge-not-awarded) !

The current description is certainly not enough , as there is a hidden condition behind this.You cant blame someone that they haven't gone through the FAQ well since the condition may be rarely noted.

Thanks for the feature request, hope the authorities will consider this soon and we will see something like this next to Mortarboard badge:

`Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day, excluding association bonus.`