# When should I close the my feature-request question?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I've [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185788/clearly-state-that-mortarboard-badge-requirements-excludes-bonuses) for feature request question. How long should I keep it opened?

**PS:** Sorry if this is a possible duplicate, I didn't find the answer via search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not up to you. There are thousands of feature requests, we can't possibly expect the team to do them all. Unlike USA government who is obliged to respond [petitions getting 100K votes](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/) Stack Exchange doesn't have such rule, feature request is only that: a request.

The team pick some feature requests from time to time, dunno if random, based on score or just according to mood, and either rejecting them or doing them thus effectively closing the requests.

Note that many times there are planned changes in design/behavior of the site that affect existing feature requests, in those cases they are also being "closed" as a side effect.

If you feel like it's been long time and you didn't get enough attention on the request, either edit it to improve and add more details or change something to make it more appealing, or start a bounty. Or both.